# Must All Database Tables be linked to at least one other table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

My question pertains to my desire to use a database table ***solely*** for the purpose of populating a DropDownList in ASP.  When the user navigates to the form, the DDL object will contain many options read from a data reader using C#.  The user will choose from this collection of data.  I would rather populate this DDL from the database than from adding ASP:ListItem entries as the list grows.
If it is not required that all database tables be linked to at least one other table, than I assume my approach to use a table to populate a DDL is valid. Am I correct?

Comment: it seems you have a very simple requirement (read from db data to populate a dropdownlist), so it's not surprising you don't need any other table and foreign key. As soon as your program will get more complicated, very likely your database design will need to change and you will have to insert relationship between tables

Comment: Thank you, Gian. I have searched for database standards regarding this question, but did not find any information regarding whether or not all tables must be linked. I was also hoping to find information if this was an industry standard, (i.e. that all tables in a db must be linked), as I did not want to break protocol standards. Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: If you store the value from the dropdown in the database, then there is a relationship. A foreign key constraint should exist to enforce the relationship in that case, although it not mandatory to do so. But if you use the value do only drive business logic, you are good as-is.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The only time you need to link tables with foreign keys is when there is some relationship between the data in the tables.

Comment: Thank you, James. I wasn't sure if stand-alone tables were allowed. I'd much rather use the db table to populate the DDL as opposed to adding ListItems. Thanks again!